# Applying pct_change based on values from another column

Tags: python, pandas

The following dataframe contains Price, and days data:

```
Date        Price       Days    
1999-01-06  1.336646    NaN
1999-01-07  1.440696    NaN
1999-01-08  1.440696    NaN
1999-01-11  1.468710    2.0
1999-01-12  1.476714    1.0
```

My expected output is to have a third column for 'Net' , which is the pct_change in price , but have that be relative to the 'Days' column .

For example, the first 'Net' would be `df['Price'].pct_change(2)`, and the second `df['Price'].pct_change(1)`etc.

Is there a way to apply lambda to include values of another column , in the current columns calculation?

Comment: I don't understand the question. In which aspect do you require help?

Comment: Im not sure how to do the operation

Comment: @Omni see edits

Answer (score 0):

A bit dirty but you can do like this:

```
df["pct"] = np.nan
for (i,row) in df.iterrows():
    if not pd.isnull(row.Days):
        try:
            pct = (row.Price - df.iloc[int(i-row.Days)].Price) / df.iloc[int(i-row.Days)].Price
            df.ix[i,"pct"] = pct
        except:
            pass
```